# Should or should we not configure ami in Chef?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra

**Scenario:**

I spin an ami for webserver1(ws1) and want to do the same for ws2, ws3, wsN.

**Question:**

How do I configure the ami in Chef for it to be scm-ed? If this is not what you practice, share your experience, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out knife-ec2 http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Launch+Cloud+Instances+with+Knife

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind Chef is that it takes a plain vanilla system and configures it according to recipes.  It's possible to create a custom AMI that's been preconfigured in some way and use it in preference to a generic one.  I've never had need to do this though but there is some package that takes a really long time to install for example, it might be worthwhile pre-installing it in your own AMI.

Having a custom AMI means you have to manage it, test it and update it.  Also I believe you need to upload it to every region you wish to use.  It's an extra moving part so in the interest of simplicity I would recommend just sticking with one of the images supplied by Amazon.

Comment: I agree and I'm looking for a reference to solution/doc to the case two that you have explained. Any resources that I can look into for handling this situation?